# RecyclerView, animate scrolling through list, animate next item, only after the first one has finished

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I took my example from here:
http://frogermcs.github.io/instamaterial-recyclerview-animations-done-right/

And then my animation looks like this:

```
  private void runEnterAnimation(View view, int position) {
    if (position > lastAnimatedPosition) {
        lastAnimatedPosition = position;
        view.setTranslationY(150*Constants.density);
        view.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(3.f))
                .setDuration(500)
                .start();
    }
}
```

And I call runEnterAnimation inside the onBindViewHolder.
Now, if I scroll through the list it works as expected. But when I  swipe to refresh, it loads the first 5 Items simultaneously. How can I make it so that the list animations will be one after another?

EDIT:
So I checked on some phones I have access to, and the screen fits 5 list items. So I did it like this:

```
   private void runEnterAnimation(View view, int position) {
    if (position > lastAnimatedPosition) {
        int speed = 1;
        lastAnimatedPosition = position;
        if(position < 5)
            speed = position+1;
        new FadeInAnimation(view).setDuration(speed * 500).animate();
    }
}
```

Where FadeInAnimation is a animation from the easyAndroidAnimations library. But. I'm still not that happy with the result, cause if I move the list after I refresh, quickly, the 6th object will fadein faster than the 5th object. But I said I'm going to share my results so far.
I'm open to any other suggestion